# infinispan with Jta at instance level

Tags: java, caching, jta, spring-transactions, infinispan

Is there a way, that I can get singleton instance of infinispan, and hence get the XA resource from instance level, (not from cache level), and enlist to the ongoing JTA transaction..!

```
ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                  builder.transaction().transactionMode(TransactionMode.TRANSACTIONAL);
                  builder.jmxStatistics().enable();
                  //builder.jmxStatistics()
                  // Construct a local cache manager using the configuration we have defined
                  DefaultCacheManager cacheManager = new DefaultCacheManager(builder.build());
```

Tried the above, which is assumed with in the jta, automatically?!!

or do I have to use,

`GenericTransactionLookup.init()`...!?
Somebody please assist me to understand it in Infinispan...!

Answer (score 3):

Creating a cache doesn't register anything with the transaction manager. Off-topic, your code creates only the cache manager, the default cache only starts when you call `getCache()`, and the same goes for any other caches in the configuration.

A transactional cache registers a new `XAResource` instance every time you invoke a cache operation and it detects a running JTA transaction. If it has detected a `TransactionManager` (via `GenericTransactionManagerLookup`) but there is no running transaction, it creates a JTA transaction first, runs the operation, and commits the JTA transaction. (With an exception for read operations.)

You can't get an `XAResource` from Infinispan to enlist manually with the JTA transaction. You can get an `XAResource` with `cache.getAdvancedCache().getXAResource()`, but you can *only* use that for recovery.

Comment: Which means, I cannot decide which cache has to be, or has not to be in transaction, once configured.. BTW how to check whether it has participated in Transaction or not...!?

Comment: As per the document, it says, it detects jta transaction.. really I can't identify any logs for that from infinispan side. Sometime the cache doesn't identify the jta getting a null jta..!!

Comment: You can avoid enlisting the cache in an existing transaction, but then you have to call `TransactionManager.suspend()` before and `TM.resume()` after.

Comment: You can enable trace logging for `org.infinispan.transaction` to get more information.

Comment: I am not able to see any sort of trace for the transactional cache.., is there any UI? where I can trace the data, after rollback?

Comment: There's no UI, I meant setting the log level to `trace` in the log4j2/log4j/etc configuration.

Comment: Hope no ! I have followed the same, and no trace of Infinispan transaction, with the above configurations..!